# How do I print double-sided with an HP Neverstop Laser 1001nw?

Tags: macos, printing, airprint

I would like to print (e.g. with Preview) a document on both sides. I also see the setting for this, but I can't change it. What do I have to do?

[image: Print dialog does not let me change the settings]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HP Neverstop 1001nw does not support duplex printing and that is why you cannot enable it.
HP has respond this to a question on [BestBuy's website](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/questions/hp-neverstop-1001nw-wireless-black-and-white-laser-printer-white/6401099/question/f14e0498-83b9-3ed0-b8e6-d411408d20c4)

From the [HP Product Page](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-neverstop-laser-1001nw):

[image]

Comment: Good to know. Then I'll have to do it manually. Who is interested, I have found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMa39SbYdiM).